# javascript string concatenation memory used

Tags: javascript, string

When we concatenate strings in javascript how many strings are created?

Given:

```
var greeting = "Hello " + "world";
```

It creates just one single string on heap (or stack: [Javascript string stored on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33125547/javascript-string-stored-on-stack)) `"Hello world"`?
or it creates 3 strings `"Hello "`, `"world"` and `"Hello world"`?

Comment: it creates two strings "Hello" and "World", then it concatenates them stores "helloworld" in greeting and garbagge collects the other strings as fast as possible. However some engines might be clever enough to do that on parsing already...

Comment: and in my opinion tozaburos answer in the link youve provided is all we can say without knowing the whole sourcecode of all available ECMA engines ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript string stored on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33125547/javascript-string-stored-on-stack)

Comment: Thanks @Jonasw, could you provide some link about what you said on your first comment? because I didn't find any resource where explains this behavior.

Comment: its pure speculation as it depends on the engine... Ive provided the two possible things an engine could do in such a case...