# How string stored in memory js

Tags: javascript

As I understand array stored in memory sequentially, string behaves pretty the same, you can get values by index, etc. Does it mean that string also stored in memory sequentially?

Comment: An array is not *necessarily* a contiguous memory allocation. It might be in some engines and even then not in all cases. It's a reasonable optimisation for speed, as it would mean easier access. But it doesn't HAVE to be that. A sparse array for example would be negatively affected from such optimisation, so some engines might opt to not keep such arrays as one big block. After all, "how x is stored in memory" is almost always implementation specific, the specs rarely specify in extreme detail.

Comment: Strange, though it has some general rules @VLAZ. Could you send anything helpfull to read on this topic ?

Comment: @AndreyRadkevich I can send you to the [official specs](https://tc39.es/ecma262/) but I doubt it's going to be helpful. After all, the specs don't mandate a particular implementation but mostly describe behaviour. Hence why *most* questions akin to "how does X get stored in memory" can be answered as "it's implementation dependant".

Comment: You could read the [V8 source code](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/objects/string.h)

Comment: @Barmar unfortunately, that requires a lot of expertise. Moreover, it's only one implementation. Other JS engines might choose to handle arrays differently. AFAIK, the array representation in memory also usually varies based on *what* the array is. An contiguous array of numbers might produce a different memory allocation to a sparse array of strings, for example.

Comment: I was only referring him to the source code specific to strings. And his question is necessarily implementation-specific, but V8 is a popular implementation.

Comment: String implementations are more complex than you may think. Some implementations intern strings, there are also optimizations that are used when you access slices or concatenate strings.

Comment: Since JavaScript is a High-level programming language, this question is "un-answerable".
If you would have asked about Assembly language, you could, probably, get a specific answer.

Comment: @developerKumar, may I make a suggestion about formatting links?
Title in Square-Braces followed by URL in Parentheses.
`[Title](URL)`
[Javascript string stored on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33125547/javascript-string-stored-on-stack)

Comment: Horrible, I've created in my mind a picture where array stored in memory sequentially, and this cause problem with deleting values from an array, etc and I need to choose a different data structures, But you say that it can be stored differently )

Comment: @iAmOren Java is also a high level language but there is very much a specific way it treats arrays. The problem isn't the *level* of the language, it's whether or not this behaviour is defined. For JavaScript it isn't and it's implementation dependant.

Comment: @AndreyRadkevich an array *acts* as if it's ordered items. Whether or not that's how it's represented in memory is not very relevant for the most part. The environment running your code might choose to optimise it in different way. It might even handle removing elements from the middle. Or it might struggle with this even more. For the most part, though, the engines have been in use and improved for more than a decade with a lot of talent and knowledge behind them. Moreover, array handling strategies are much older. So *usually* your code shouldn't really run into big problems.