# How strings and numbers are stored in memory？

Tags: javascript, string

as we know, both strings and numbers are stored in binary.

- strings:

stored as ASSCII or Unicode,which transform string to binary, eg. letter `A` is 65 or `01000001`

- numbers:

stored as Int or floating point numbers

letter `A` and number 65 is same in binary，so how to distinguish them ? i had search a lot, but no help.

Comment: What are you trying to do where you are needing to distinguish them? May you share that?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a practical programming question, and the answers might vary depending on the implementation. Some basics can be found on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33125547/javascript-string-stored-on-stack).

Comment: You cannot even get the raw memory value in JavaScript. You'd have to examine the application using an outside tool. I'm not an expert there but at least Cheat Engine (really, more of a memory scanner and decompiler) can distinguish whether a memory value is a string, integer, float, or double. So, however you're actually examining these, it *should be possible* to determine the datatype from memory information alone.

Answer (score 1):

> letter A and number 65 is same in binary，so how to distinguish them?

You can't*. If you program in a "systems" language (C, Rust etc) you're supposed to *know* what kind of value is stored under a specific address. If you use a scripting language, then there's an underlying C implementation which knows what is where.

- Assuming a non-tagged architecture (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_architecture for details)

Comment: tks  it helps me a lot